# Virtual device trying to open base.dm instead of base.apk in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android Studio and don't understand a lot of how the virtual device works. I have followed a tutorial to make an app, but when running it on the virtual device, it shows a white screen. These are the first lines of the logcat:

2023-08-27 14:14:51.280 12681-12681 Compatibil...geReporter com.example.myapplication            D  Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10183; state: ENABLED
2023-08-27 14:14:51.286 12681-12681 Compatibil...geReporter com.example.myapplication            D  Compat change id reported: 242716250; UID 10183; state: DISABLED
2023-08-27 14:14:51.432 12681-12681 ziparchive              com.example.myapplication            W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~_UZBc89aV6_L-EjF44iNeg==/com.example.myapplication-PGRmfGsriJz5xb8sPhyGLg==/base.dm': No such file or directory

I can see in the folder of the virtual device that it has base.apk instead of base.dm. Why does it try to open base.dm instead, what does it mean?

I have tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it, it didn't work.